# About the boundary of the $x$-section of a bounded domain

Tags: general-topology, projection

Decompose $\mathbb{R}^N = \mathbb{R}^{N_1} \times \mathbb{R}^{N_2}$, let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ be a bounded domain and take $x$ in the set
$$\Pi_1(\Omega) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^{N_1} : (x,y) \in \Omega \text{ for some } y \in \mathbb{R}^{N_2}\}.
$$
Define the set
$$
A_x := \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{N_2} : (x,y) \in \Omega\}.
$$
I am trying to discover what should be the boundary of $A_x$. My first attempt was
$$
(1) \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\partial A_x = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^{N_2} : (x,y) \in \partial \Omega\},
$$
what, I think, is not true.

Edit: For me it is enough to prove: If $y \in \partial A_x$ then $(x,y) \in \partial \Omega$. Is it true ? Here there is a drawing which shows that (1) may not be true:
[image]

Notice that $x$ in the picture is in $\Pi_1(\Omega)$ and $y_0$ in the picture is in $\{y \in \mathbb{R}^{N_2} : (x,y) \in \partial \Omega\}$. However $y_0 \not\in \partial A_x$.

Comment: Seems right to me; why don't you think it's true?

Comment: Thank you. By domain I mean an open set with smooth boundary, I mean, locally, the boundary is a gragp of a smooth function.

Comment: In the case of square I think what I wrote works. For example, let $\Omega = (1,2) \times (1,2)$. Notice that $1/2 \in \Pi_1(\Omega)$ and $A_{1/2} = (1,2)$. Clearly $\partial A_{1/2} = \{1,2\}$. Also, $\{y \in \mathbb{R} : (1/2, y) \in \partial \Omega\} = \{1,2\}$. However I think what I said is not true for a general domain. In this case, how to describe $\partial A_x$ in general ?

Comment: I tryied, but I got stuck. I just put a drawing which shows more or less why I got stuck.

Comment: It is a good example, I was quite careless in my comments. The implications in the edit is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all $x\in \mathbb R^{N_1}$, the inclusion
$$
\{x\}  \times \partial A_x \subset \partial \Omega\quad (*)
$$
(that you are asking about in the end of the edit) is true. At the same time, as your example shows, the opposite inclusion is false even if you assume that $A$ is open with smooth boundary and $x\in \Pi_1(A)$.

Let's prove the inclusion (*). (I do not need any assumptions on $A$ and $x$.) Take $p=(x,y)$ such that $y\in \partial A_x$. Let $U=U_x\times U_y$ be a product neighborhood of $p$. Since product neighborhoods form a basis of topology at $p$, it suffices to prove that every such $U$ has nonempty intersection with both $A$ and its complement $A^c$ in $\mathbb R^N$. Since $y\in \partial A_x$, there exists $z\in A_x\cap U_y$. The point $(x,z)\in A$ lies in $U$ since $x\in U_x$. Thus, $U\cap A\ne \emptyset$. Furthermore,  since $y\in \partial A_x$, there exists $w\in U_y\setminus A_x$. Then $(x,w)\notin A$ either. Hence, $U\cap A^c\ne\emptyset$ as well. Thus, $p\in \partial A$. qed

Addendum. Call a boundary point $p\in \partial A$ **hidden** if the equality in (*) fails. One can prove that, in a sense, $p$ can be hidden only in the situation described in your example. More precisely, assuming that $A$ is open with smooth boundary, and $p$ is a hidden boundary point then the affine subspace $\{x\}\times {\mathbb R}^{N_2}$ is contained in the tangent space $T_p\partial A$. (But the inclusion
$\{x\}\times {\mathbb R}^{N_2}\subset T_p\partial A$ does not imply that $p$ is hidden.)